# how to get detail of all digital assets used in single webpage in AEM

Tags: java, adobe, aem, wcm

how to get details of all digital assets used in single webpage in AEM(Adobe experience manager). is there any out of box utility.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you need to search in a java class there is class called 
[AssetReferenceSearch](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/commons/util/AssetReferenceSearch.html) . It's constructor takes the node (content node of the page ) to search under , path where the assets are stored (can be /content/dam ) and Resource Resolver.

Reference : http://wemcode.wemblog.com/get_asset_reference_in_page

In case you want it as json over HTTP , there is a servlet already that returns the references ( /libs/wcm/core/content/reference ).

[http://localhost:4502/libs/wcm/core/content/reference.json?path=%2Fcontent%2Fgeometrixx%2Fen&*charset*=UTF-8&_dc=1434561074057](http://localhost:4502/libs/wcm/core/content/reference.json?path=%2Fcontent%2Fgeometrixx%2Fen&_charset_=UTF-8&_dc=1434561074057) returns asset references in the geometrixx home page.

Comment: Thanks ......" "http://localhost:4502/libs/wcm/core/content/reference.json?path=%2Fcontent%2Fgeometrixx%2Fen&_charset_=UTF-8&_dc=1434561074057 " done 80% of my  work ........Thanks alot ...next how can i see digital asset of reference page in a page ...is there any json like above one ....please share some view on it ...thanks in advance